# CCSpriteBatchNode to animate single sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

As far as I understand, CCSpriteBatchNode's role is to optimize rendering of many children by reducing the number of OpenGL instructions (if they all use the same spritesheet).

But I saw in the [Cocos2D animation guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aanimation) that CCSpriteBatchNode is used to animate a single sprite...

I'm a bit confused. Is there any benefit to use CCSpriteBatchNode to animate one single CCSprite? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. If you only have a single sprite on screen using a CCSpriteBatchNode is counterproductive, whether the sprite is animated or not.

Comment: It's correct assuming you want to display multiple sprites, which is the common use case. So it does teach best practices. But the guide also incorrectly says that CCSpriteBatchNode is required to do this, which it is not.